# python opening files from multiple directories(folders)

Tags: python, operating-system

I have multiple files in multiple directories and would like to iterate each directory to be run for my code. I have written code like this.

```
import os

path = [".\\folder1\\",".\\forder2\\"]
for i in path:
    # print (i) # test
    for filename in os.listdir(i):
        filedata = open(i+filename,"r")
        data = filedata.read().split()
        string = "".join(data)
        filedata.close()
```

However, it gets error due to the i is not specific.
Each folder contains strings of characters and access them through os.listdir.

How can I overcome this problem when reading files from multiple directories?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you going to have a changing number of files, or is it just two?

Comment: Actually i'm going to change the number of directories which that I will add on the list 'path'. I suppose os.listdir read all the files in a directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `os.path.join`

```
path = ["folder1", "folder2"]
for i in path:
    for filename in os.listdir(i):
        with open(os.path.join(i, filename), 'r') as filedata:
            string = "".join(filedata.read().split())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it gets 'TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()' and also '~~in join assert len(path) >0'
I don't get the message and the error is not specific... hope there are any other suggestions.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I used same variable ,the 'i', twice along my code!
This works perfectly! Thank you Josha!